# @ComponentScan in Play Framework

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, playframework

I am trying to dynamically load at runtime,  custom Plugin classes placed into a directory  in a Play framework project. Does anybody know if there is a   mechanism like Spring's @ComponentScan in Play framework?

Thanks